# How to register custom Blueprint macros in OctoberCMS & WinterCMS

Tags: php, laravel, database, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I have like this service provider where I try add custom Blueprint macros to use in migrations:

```
<?php

namespace My\Plugin\Providers;

use Winter\Storm\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Winter\Storm\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class PluginServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{    
    public function register()
    {
        $this->registerBlueprintMacros();
    }

    /**
     * Register the blueprint macros.
     */
    protected function registerBlueprintMacros(): void
    {
        Blueprint::macro('productDates', function () {
            $this->boolean('enabled')->default(false)->index();
            $this->timestamp('starts_at')->nullable()->index();
            $this->timestamp('ends_at')->nullable()->index();
        }); 
    }
}
```

Then I will register this service provider inside my `Plugin.php` file like this:

```
public function register()
{
    // Register the service provider
    $this->app->register(PluginServiceProvider::class);
}
```

Then when I try use registered columns in my migration:

```
Schema::create('plugin_products', function($table)
{
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('title');
    $table->text('description')->nullable();
    // Usage example
    $table->productDates();
});
```

Get error message:

> Method `Winter\Storm\Database\Schema\Blueprint::productDates` does not
> exist.

How I can correctly register custom Blueprint macros in OctoberCMS & WinterCMS?

Comment: Not familiar with OctoberCMS, but one of the reasons this error might occur is if the migration runs before the ServiceProvider is registered.